# How do I apply a patch from gist to the Django source?

Tags: python, git, github, patch

I want to try out a patch on gist that modifies the source code of Django:

[gist: 550436](http://gist.github.com/550436)

How do I do it? I have never used git so a step by step instruction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you track your local copy of Django using git? In that case it is as easy as downloading the patch and executing `git apply`. http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html

Comment: I actually use mercurial for my projects. Is there any way to use mercurial to apply the patch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `patch` to apply diffs. Make sure you're in your django source directory (or wherever you want to apply the patch), and run something like `patch -p1 < downloaded-patch.diff`.

You may want to experiment with the `-p` argument if it fails; -p tells `patch` to strip some of the directory prefix for each file in the diff (look at the first line in the diff).